# Missing viewfield column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I'm attempting to use SP services to get some information from a list. Everything seems to be going fine except for one column in the list.

The column in question is a drop down selection of choices for which not every entry has populated with information.

Using the console I can see every other table I setup in the viewfield except for the status field. Any ideas why? Oh Also this is using sharepoint 365 and using the same CAML query with a 3rd Party tool I get back a table of results including the status column.

Here is the code:

```
query = "<Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='JobCreationDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2012-10-31T12:00:00Z</Value></Geq></Where></Query>";

query = "<Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='JobCreationDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2012-10-31T12:00:00Z</Value></Geq></Where></Query>";


$().SPServices({
        webURL: siteURL,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: listName,

        CAMLQuery: query,
        CAMLViewFields: viewFields,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
        {       
            debug = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
            node: xData.responseXML
            });

            //$("#DeltaFormDigest").html("").append("<b>This is the output from the GetList operation:</b>" + debug);
            if($(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").length==0)
            {
            alert("There is no data");
            }else{
                $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function()
                {
                    tmp = xData;
                    //SET DEFAULT VALUES
                    var theData ="";
                    var dueDate;
                    var finalDueDate;

                    //LOAD ALL OF THE VALUES
                    var projectStatus = $(this).attr('ows_Status');
                    var businessUnit = $(this).attr('ows_JobType');
                    var shortName = $(this).attr('ows_ProjectName');
                    var projectName = $(this).attr('ows_ProjectName');
                    var projectManager = $(this).attr('ows_ProjectManager');
//...Code continues on from this point
```

Answer (score 0):

If the particular item does not contain a value in that field, it is not returned in the XML. So in your output, you'd need to do something like this in the each function of your completefunc:

```
var theChoiceField;
if ($(this).attr('ows_ChoiceField')) {theChoiceField = $(this).attr('ows_ChoiceField')}
else {theChoiceField = "Not Supplied"; }
```